# MySQLi query returns bool(false) even knowing the SQL is correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

The following query returns `bool(false)` when dumping the query:

```
        SELECT *
        FROM `account` 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `player` ON `account`.`uid` = `player`.`account_uid` 
        UNION 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN `player` ON `account`.`uid` = `player`.`account_uid`
```

I know that if the query returns false there was an error with the SQL however I'm sure the syntax is correct, I even ran it successful in my console and on phpMyAdmins SQL tool.

If I run it without

```
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `player` ON `account`.`uid` = `player`.`account_uid` 
        UNION 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN `player` ON `account`.`uid` = `player`.`account_uid`
```

all is working.

What is the problem with my query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not run this query successfully in any query tool that I know of.  The syntax is not correct.

Comment: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/gnUvkbB.png) There. Successfully ran it again. What do you think is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: `UNION RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is not accepted syntax.  I assume that is why the `RIGHT` is underlined in the query tool.

Comment: @GordonLinoff every function is underlined.

Comment: @BeetleJuice I don't get an error thts the issue i have

Comment: Show your PHP usage. If the query works as you stated it does then it must be the PHP usage. When executing the query do you check for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself by adding another

```
SELECT * FROM `account`
```

to the query. The full query now looks like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `account` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `player` ON `account`.`uid` = `player`.`account_uid` 
    UNION 
    SELECT *
    FROM `account`
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN `player` ON `account`.`uid` = `player`.`account_uid`
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to post the fix. To be fair, you didn't do a good job of helping us help you. You insisted the query executed successfully when someone tried to tell you that its syntax was incorrect. You said you received no error message but when the query returns `false` it means there is an error message. To see it, call `$mysqli->error` or `mysqli_error`. Glad you worked it out though.

Comment: @BeetleJuice The query did execute correctly the whole time but not when I used it with php which I still don't know why this happened.